# What em.merge will do with the state of detached entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, openjpa

I have code like this

```
private Identifiable updateEntityInternal(JPABaseEntity entity) {

        Identifiable updated = null;
        try {
            updated = em.merge(entity);
            em.flush();
```

As I understand **em.merge** creates new entity, copy state from "old" entity to the new one, new entity is managed, "old" one is detached.

I need retrieve some property (array, Lazy init) from entity.

So what will happen if entity that I am populating to this api is already detached. Does it mean that while merging (copying the state) it can't retrieve array from entity I am passing because it is detached? So new managed entity after merge will not have this array?

Answer (score 0):

No .... If the detached entity didn't contain the collection because it was not loaded due to lazy loading, then you try to merge it again, it will be with the same state (as if it has a unloaded collection due to its lazy loading) .... but if initially you loaded the collection (by calling its getter explicitly for example) then you set it to null then you detach it and try to merge it again, it will be saved with a null reference to the collection (i.e. with an empty collection)